# How do I use data from a UDP segment to establish a TCP connections?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

I have received data from UDP socket `fd`. How can I use this information to establish a TCP connection from the sender. `buf` contains the TCP port.

```
struct sockaddr_storage remote_addr;
socklen_t remote_addr_len;

recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_addr, &remote_addr_len);
```

The code below is my attempt, but it doesn't work. I am new to socket programming and I am tearing my hair over trying to figure this out.

```
newfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
struct hostent *info;
info = gethostbyname(remoteAddr.h_addr);

struct sockaddr_in newConn;
newConn.sin_family = AF_INET;
bcopy((char *)info->h_addr, (char *)&newConn.sin_addr.s_addr, info->h_length);
newConn.sin_port = htons(mesgTcpPort); //mesgTcpPort is of type int gotten from buf


connect(newfd,(struct sockaddr *)&newConn,sizeof newConn);
```

Error checking is omitted.

Comment: If you add error checking, what errors do you get? (If you didn't get any, your code would be working.)

Comment: I have error checking in the actual code, I just removed it here to keep the code short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need `gethostbyname`, since the UDP packet contains an IP address, not a name, in its header (and given to you by `recvfrom`).

However, this approach has limited applicability, since the new connection won't traverse NAT because it won't be associated with the original UDP connection, since the protocol and port differ.